# Firestore queries: Invalid Payload Received

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

**What am I trying to do?**

Query the field named `price` in documents inside the collection named `product_page` and return the document where price==100

**What did I do?**

URL:https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects//databases/(default)/documents/product_page/

METHOD: **POST**

Request Body:

```
{
  "structuredQuery": {
    "from": [
      {
        "collectionId": "product_page",
        "allDescendants": true
      }
    ],
    "where": {
      "fieldFilter": {
        "field": {
          "fieldPath": "price"
        },
        "op": "EQUAL",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "100"
        }
      }
    }
```

**What error do I get?**

```
code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"structuredQuery\" at 'document': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "document",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"structuredQuery\" at 'document': Cannot find field."
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the wrong endpoint (or method).

With the following URL and a POST method

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/.../databases/(default)/documents/product_page
```

you actually call the [`createDocument`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument?authuser=2&hl=en) method.

---

You need to use the [`runQuery`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery?authuser=2&hl=en) method, which allows passing a `structuredQuery` object.

---

**Update following your comment:**

You need to pass the following JSON as the payload pf the POST request:

```
{
    "from": [
      {
        "collectionId": "product_page",
        "allDescendants": true
      }
    ],
    "where": {
      "fieldFilter": {
        "field": {
          "fieldPath": "price"
        },
        "op": "EQUAL",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "100"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: @reanud it actually throws me an invalid JSON error. Can you please check what is wrong with my JSON? Also, when you ask me to use runQuery method, i should just use `:runQuery` at the end of the URL right?

Comment: Yes you need to add `:runQuery` at the end of the URL. And you'll find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery?authuser=2&hl=en) the doc on the `StructuredQuery`object.

Comment: Hey @xcrystal360, did you have time to look a the proposed resolution?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. Unfortunately, the proposed solution returns the same error. Might it be that I'm making some mistake in the request body?